# Pass PHP object via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, object

I was wondering what the best way would be to pass a php object via AJAX.

for example

```
//objectClass = objectClass.php
$obj = new objectClass();
<a href="javascript:getOutput("some variable", $obj);
```

As the other file i.e. output.php (called through ajax in getOutput() function) needs to access objectClass.php as well, what is the best way to access $obj?

I tried to jscon_encode($obj) then decode but not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try [PHP Object Serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php) -- Perhaps serialize the object to transfer then unserialize it when it's received.

Comment: JSON is the way to go. Show your code.

Comment: Take care that while serialization is the simple alternative, unserializing is not without exploitability. The other option is just passing the object over the `$_SESSION` store.

Comment: @mario Am I correct in assuming you're speaking of a man-in-the-middle sort of situation where someone intercepts the serialized string and manipulates it? Just interested in your thought process ...

Comment: @rdlowrey: If it's accessible via AJAX or just a form really, then anyone could pass a specifically crafted serialize blob. Some class types can run passed code, and there were some overflowish exploits for it http://blog.nibbles.fr/1837

Comment: @mario Interesting -- thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, it's going to be easiest to just store the information that needs passed (in this case an object) in a session variable like @mario suggested. If you need it to be a dynamically named session variable, you could just pass the name(string) of the session variable via AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

json_encode is the best way.

You need to use ' instead of " for href argument, and add JSON_HEX_APOS option to json_encode to escape any ' in JSON.

Use it like this:

```
<?php
    //objectClass = objectClass.php
    $obj = new objectClass();
?>    
<a href='javascript:getOutput(<?php echo $some_variable ?>,<?php echo json_encode ($obj, JSON_HEX_APOS) ?>);'></a>
```

or

```
<?php
    //objectClass = objectClass.php
    $obj = new objectClass();    
    echo "<a href='javascript:getOutput($some_variable, " . json_encode ($obj, JSON_HEX_APOS) . " );'></a>"
?>
```

EDIT:
If you have jQuery, I recommend using jQuery.parse () to load JSON. If not, you can use JSON.parse (), but I don't know if it's compatible with archaic browsers. Anyway you should be fine without them (just check for XSS on your server-side).

Comment: thanks for you repsonse - when I decoded the JSON it was always empty :(

Comment: That's weird. Because this code works:
http://pastebin.com/TFTGckZE

Maybe you're class is wrong